# How can i get a list of resources that use Basic SKU in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell

Microsoft has outlined that On 30 September 2025, Basic SKU public IP addresses will be retired in Azure. I have used Basic SKU public IP addresses in the last 30 days.
I am trying to get a list of resources that use Basic SKU via the following , but it times out .

GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/skus?api-version=2021-07-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/providers/Microsoft.Compute/skus?api-version=2021-07-01)

Is there a way i can get it using Powershell ?
Also in order to avoid any issues in the future can i just upgrade to Standard SKU public IP addresses ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command to list all Public IP addresses in one subscription that are using the Basic SKU.

```
Get-AzPublicIpAddress | Where-Object { $_.Sku.Name -eq 'Basic' }
```

You can also query the Resource Graph in order to get the corresponding Public IP addresses across all subscriptions in your tenant:

```
Search-AzGraph -Query "resources | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses' | where sku.name =~ 'Basic'"
```

You can upgrade to Standard SKU if the IP address is disassociated and has static allocation method.

Comment: So  if the IP address is disassociated and has static allocation method, can i still connect for example to my VM via RDP ?

Comment: do i need to change sku for an app service , is the sku attached to an app service ? or the App Service Plan the app is attached to , will those be affected ?  Its basically the Pricing tier , just wondering since its basic will it need to be upgraded before 2025 ?